# Import is erroring with all modules in the root

Tags: micropython

Noob to Raspberry and Python but otherwise experienced (i.e. tech and development) here.

In the root of my Pico, I have these files:

[image]

mpu9250_jmdev.fake_smbus.py contains this.

```
class FakeSmbus(object): 

class SMBus(object): 
    
    def __init__(self, bus): 
        pass 
    
    def write_byte_data(self, a, b, c): 
        pass 
    
    def read_byte_data(self, a, b): 
        return 0 
        
    def read_i2c_block_data(self, a, b, c): 
        return [0] * c
        
    def close(self): 
        pass
```

My test.py contains this:

```
from mpu9250_jmdev.fake_smbus import FakeSmbus
```

but when running it, I get this:

```
ImportError: no module named 'mpu9250_jmdev.fake_smbus'
```

Can anyone spot my error?

Comment: what happens if you remove the `from` directive?

Comment: Huh.  that works.  Any idea why?  Thank you.

Comment: do some research about python libraries ... forget about the Raspberry Pi when you do this